# Positive Directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ having positive directional derivative in any direction of (any unit vector) $u \in \mathbb R^n$? (for any $n \in \mathbb N$)

Comment: In one particular point, yes. Everywhere, no.

Comment: Please learn TeX/MathJax!

Answer (score 0):

At any point x The directional derivative in the direction -u is - ( the directional derivative in the direction u ) so there is no such function .

Comment: I was assuming just that the directional derivative at x in the direction u is the derivative (2 sided }with respect to t at t=0 of the function whose value at t is f(x+t u) . If you want to take the derivative from the + side ,that means restrict t to t >= o then your example comment is right at (0,0) only .For points where a function is differentiable iit is impossible .